# Unusual setdefault's in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Here's a piece of code from [Django's authentification models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py) (UserManager):

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Why set a key-value pair and check it immediately afterwards? In what scenario would these conditions be met?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) sets the value only if the key is not already present in the dict. The caller of the function could still pass `extra_fields` with some values of `id_staff` or `is_superuser`.

What this function does is that while creating a superuser if the calling function is not providing any values then set `is_staff` and `is_superuser` both to True for this user.

But, if the values are provided then check if those are `True` and raise exceptions otherwise.

Comment: That's the answer, yup.

Comment: Thanks. Damn, this was a dumb question :( I even read the docs beforehand.